# Oracle PL/SQL function: if parameter not in table column => continue program

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql

Please see my code below. If the parameter `p_cust_id` is not in the column `cust_id` I want "0" to be printed out (which means not logged in). If it is in `cust_id` I want oracle to continue the second part of the code (the part below the empty row).

I have tried to solve this by inserting the values of column `cust_id` in a cursor and then inserting it in the variable `v_cust_id`. Perhaps this results in unnecessarily much code?

My problem is that the program does not seem to run the second part even if `p_cust_id` is in `cust_id`. It just prints out "0" even though the customer ID and the password are correct.

Before I added the cursor the program worked as it was supposed to, unless the parameter `p_cust_id` didn't match any value in the `cust_id` column. If this was the case nothing was printed out.

```
create or replace function log_in(
  p_cust_id in customer.cust_id%type,
  p_passwd in customer.passwd%type)
return varchar2
as
  cursor c_cust_id is select cust_id from customer;
  v_cust_id customer.cust_id%type;
  v_passwd customer.passwd%type;
  v_logged_in number(1);
  v_not_logged_in number(1);
begin
v_logged_in := 1;
v_not_logged_in := 0;
if not c_cust_id%isopen then
open c_cust_id;
end if;
loop
  fetch c_cust_id
  into v_cust_id;
  exit when c_cust_id%notfound;
end loop;
if p_cust_id not in(v_cust_id) then
  return v_not_logged_in;
end if;
close c_cust_id;

select passwd
into v_passwd
from customer
where cust_id = p_cust_id;
if v_passwd = p_passwd then
 return v_logged_in;
else
 return v_not_logged_in; 
end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see, you don't need a cursor at all, to check if the `cust_id` is in the table. Just search for the `cust_id` in the table, and attempt to fetch the password. If it exists, you get the value, and `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception otherwise which means not logged in.

```
BEGIN 
  select passwd
    into v_passwd
  from customer
   where cust_id = p_cust_id;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  return v_not_logged_in;
END;
```

Full code will be:

```
create or replace function log_in(
  p_cust_id in customer.cust_id%type,
  p_passwd in customer.passwd%type)
return varchar2
as
  v_cust_id customer.cust_id%type;
  v_passwd customer.passwd%type;
  v_logged_in number(1);
  v_not_logged_in number(1);
begin
v_logged_in := 1;
v_not_logged_in := 0;

BEGIN 
  select passwd
    into v_passwd
  from customer
   where cust_id = p_cust_id;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  return v_not_logged_in;
END;

if v_passwd = p_passwd then
 return v_logged_in;
else
 return v_not_logged_in; 
end if;
end;
```